# PyQGIS ogr provider not Found

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I using PyQGIS in my python application，My program couldn't find org provider and failed to create layer.

My code and environment are as follows.

The env:

[image]

The Code:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMainWindow


class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, layer):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.gray)

        self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self.canvas.setLayers([layer])

        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.actionZoomIn = QAction("放大", self)
        self.actionZoomOut = QAction("缩小", self)
        self.actionPan = QAction("平移", self)

        self.actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionPan.setCheckable(True)

        self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
        self.actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.zoomOut)
        self.actionPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Canvas actions")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomOut)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionPan)

        # create the map tools
        self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.toolPan.setAction(self.actionPan)
        self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False)  # false = in
        self.toolZoomIn.setAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True)  # true = out
        self.toolZoomOut.setAction(self.actionZoomOut)

        self.pan()

    def zoomIn(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomIn)

    def zoomOut(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomOut)

    def pan(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPan)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = QgsApplication([], True)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('D:/Program Files/QGIS 3.4/apps/qgis-ltr1', True)

    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    print(QgsApplication.showSettings())

    print(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().pluginList())

    r = QgsProviderRegistry.instance()
    if not 'ogr' in r.providerList():
        print('Could not find OGR provider!')
    else:
        print('Providers found ok!')

    layer = QgsVectorLayer("E:\\cosm-gis-demo\\data\\data\\guodao2.shp", "buildings", "ogr")
    if not layer.isValid():
        print("failed")
    mainWindow = MyWnd(layer)
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("GIS Demo")
    mainWindow.show()

    a.exec_()
```

The Console:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Can you replace your Console image by a text block of the error code, it will be more simple for referencing and finding similar errors.